# How to get the gradient of a max ? (intersection of SDFs)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm experimenting with signed distance functions and constructive solid geometry.

Most operations, like union, intersection, difference can be represented by mins and maxs on the signed distance fuction. Now, I'm using those SDF's gradients to find the surface of those CSG solids using a gradient descent method.

But how can I get the gradient of an intersection ? I'm able to draw it out on a paper, what I would like it to be, but can't find a general operation.

My signed distance functions are negative inside the objects, null at the surface and positive on the outside. So for instance, the SDF of a sphere would be :

$$SDF_{sphere}(x) = ||p - x|| - r$$

Where $p$ is the center of the sphere and $r$ the radius. So the gradient of this sphere would be :

$$GradSDF_{sphere}(x) = \frac{p-x}{||p-x||}$$

If I want to intersect two of these spheres, I take the max of their SDFs :

$$SDF_{intersection}(x) = max(SDF_{sphere1}(x), SDF_{sphere2}(x))$$

But then, what would the gradient look like ?

Comment: Something like : $$H(SDF_{inter}-SDF_1)*\frac{p_1-x_1}{\|p_1-x_1\|}+H(SDF_{inter}-SDF_2)*\frac{p_2-x_2}{\|p_2-x_2\|}$$ where $H$ is the Heaviside function (not sure the expression is the right one).

Comment: @JeanMarie So some kind of conditionnal functions ? The thing is I don't know what to expect when the two SDFs would be equal, for the example of two sphere, it should still lead to the point on the segment made by the two sphere's centers, where the SDF have the same value, but with this expression it could be null ?

Comment: You are right and I have no answer...